# How to deal with onClick event?

Tags: javascript, html

For instance, I have li. Inside I have paragraphs, spans...

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <p>ABC</p>
    <span>ABC</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I try to manage with `onClick` event I notice that target elements are sometimes a paragraph, sometimes a span. But I certainly need a `li` as a target element when I click on it or on tags inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) instead of `event.target` - it always refers to the element you actually attached the listener to, not the element that the Event originally triggered on.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an id for the element where you want to add onclick. For example-

```html
<ul>
<li id="demo" onclick="myFunction()">
<p>ABC</p>

<span>ABC</span>
</li>
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.color = "red";
}
</script>
```

If you click now any items (i.e, paragraph or span) inside the li, including li also, then the function will work.